# Visual Studio 2012 Hot towel template not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, single-page-application, hottowel

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=910) for getting started with *Hot towel*, I have installed the *ASP.NET Web Tools 2012.2 update* and have also downloaded and installed the VSIX for the *Hot towel* template, but when I try create a new project with this template it is not working correctly. If I open a new project in *Visual Studio 2012* and select *ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application* I see the *HotTowel Single Page Application* template listed there, but I select the project gets created with a lot of files missing.

What I would expect to see in my *Scripts* folder is the following:

[image]

But instead my project looks like this:

[image]

The project created also does not compile, it throws the following exception:

```
Error 1 The name 'BundleConfig' does not exist in the current context
```

This exception is being thrown here:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the *Hot towel* template is not working correctly in *Visual Studio 2012* and what I could do to get it working?

UPDATE:

I tried installing *Hot Towel* with *Nuget* instead of the template, but that also did not work correctly. *Install-Package* got as far as installing *Q* and then gave an exception. Here is the *Nuget* output:

```
PM> Install-Package HotTowel
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.WebApi (≥ 1.4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.Client (≥ 1.4.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Q'.
Install-Package : External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package HotTowel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by updating *NuGet Package Manager*. I updated it from here:

```
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget
```

Comment: So bizarre, but this also solved it for me. I'm running VS 2012